# Hard coding value or converting in regular expression

Tags: regex, replace, expression

I have a regular expression that I took time to write researching on here but it isnt doing exactly what I wanted. The value I am trying to pull is something like this:

```
DATE OF SURGERY:  08/06/2013
```

I want to pull the date, but i want to turn the slashes into dashes. I wrote this:

```
(?<=DATE OF SURGERY: *)\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}
```

This allows me to pull back 08/06/2013 but i need it to pull back 08-03-2013. Is there a way for me to hardcode the dashes in the regular expression? or is there a replace way i could replace the slashes with dashes? Thank you all

Comment: Do you want it to match slashes OR dashes?

Comment: You can do a replace and if the string has slashes only for the dates, a simple global replace would turn `DATE OF SURGERY:  08/06/2013` into `DATE OF SURGERY:  08-06-2013` and if you only want the date, that's possible in one step as well. The replace now can be called differently depending on the language you're using.

Comment: You'll have to do it in two steps, as far as I know. Pull the date, then replace `/` with `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is that you want to match strings like `DATE OF SURGERY: 08/06/2013` or `DATE OF SURGERY: 08-06-2013`, you could use this pattern:

```
(?<=DATE OF SURGERY: *)\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,4}
```

But that would catch mixed slashes or hyphens `DATE OF SURGERY:  08/06-2013` as well. If you only want to get two slashes or two hyphens, you need to use a back reference:

```
(?<=DATE OF SURGERY: *)\d{1,2}([/-])\d{1,2}\1\d{1,4}
```

If what you mean is that you'd like to use regular expressions to replace `DATE OF SURGERY: 08/06/2013` with `DATE OF SURGERY: 08-06-2013`, well you'll need to use a replacement pattern like this:

```
match: (?<=DATE OF SURGERY: *)(\d{1,2})([/-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,4})

replace: \1-\3-\4
```

For example, this is C#, but the actual code you use will depend on your particular language and regular expression engine:

```cs
Regex.Replace(input, 
    @"(?<=DATE OF SURGERY: *)(\d{1,2})([/-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,4})",
    @"\1-\3-\4");
```

Comment: Thanks pswg...that helps me out...but I am trying to do it in one step bc the program I am using calls this regex and I can only give it one step. ultimately i need one of two outcomes in the output within one step

the input is
08/06/2013

I need the output from the regex lookup to be either 
08062013 or
08-06-2013

Comment: As others have pointed out, regular expressions can validate a string or perform replacements, but they cannot be used for general purpose programming. If this is a custom program that you cannot change, you may need to pre-process the results by sending it through some other program first. If you tell us what language you're or tools you're using, perhaps we can give you more complete advice, but that would probably be better suited to a different question.

Comment: it is in C sharp some and in vb.net in some other areas. It is a program our developers wrote and I can only give it one expression which it sounds like I cannot do because i cannot manipulate the incoming data, but just grab what is given to me